# Change of Argument

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Consider the function $f(x)= x^6-1+ix$. Let $[0,R]$ be the real axis in the complex plane where $R$ is really large.

Find the change of argument of $f(x)$ on $[0,R]$.

Observe that $arg(f(x))=$ $arctan(\frac{x}{x^{6}-1})$, which has a discontinuity when $x=1$ . Observe that $\frac{x}{x^{6}-1}$ is continuous on $[0,1)$ and $(1,R]$. Further observe that when $x=0$, $\frac{x}{x^{6}-1}$ is $0$ and when we approach $1$ from the left hand side, the argument becomes $-\frac{\pi}{2}$. Since $R$ is very large the argument becomes approximately 0. So the change of argument of $f$ in the contour $[0,R]$ is approximately
$0+\frac{pi}{2} +\frac{pi}{2} -0$ $=\pi$

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Even if the 'final argument' is 'aligned' with $0
$, the trajectory can wind around the origin many times as $x$ increases. Your solution does not seem to take this into account.

Comment: [Be careful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: $f(0) = -1 + 0i$. What is $\arg(-1)$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair $arg(x+iy)$ $=$ $arctan(y/x)$ so $arg(-1)$ $=$ $0$?

Comment: So you think both $1$ and $-1$ have the same argument despite being on opposite sides of $0$?